# Union not working as I expect

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that a person can be on. I want to find their instances on each table and union them together. I am hoping that the union will find all instances of this person on both tables, and remove any redundant instances. So if a person were on table A but not B, they would show up. If vice versa, they would still show up. If they were on both, they would show up. But I only want one instance of the person in the result set. Right now, as per the data I saw in the database, the person has one instance in both tables, but could have more in other situations. This is supposed to return one row, rather than two because the redundancy should be removed, but it returns nothing (0). No errors at all, the query is just wrong and I am misunderstanding union and somehow getting zero matches back.

```
SqlCommand getDrivers = new SqlCommand("SELECT DriverPhone FROM Transactions WHERE EstablishmentCode = @ec UNION SELECT PhoneNumber FROM Connection WHERE EstablishmentCode = @ec AND Dispatcher = @disp", myTransactions);
    getDrivers.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ec", "ec");
    getDrivers.Parameters.AddWithValue("@disp", false);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = getDrivers;
    try
    {
        adapter.Fill(dsDrivers);
        adapter.Dispose();
        getDrivers.Dispose();
        Response.Write(dsDrivers.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Response.Write("<p>" + err + "</p>");
        //sb.Append("<p style='display:none'>" + err + "</p>");   // shows real error msg for debug but hides it on page
    }
```

Comment: The query seems right .. but be sure the column have the same type and the where condition work correctly .. (could  be you don't manage in proper way the var @ec ...or other)

Comment: Does the @disp parameter need to be a string as well?

Comment: @disp corresponds to a bool/bit column, so I thought that entering false would be correct. Not sure. Does it have to be 0 or 1? This is sql server, not my sql

Comment: both sets of columns have the same data type, however there is an additional filter in the second part of the query

Comment: I think for false it needs to be 0.

Comment: are you sure @disp is a boolean?  it looks more like dispatcher, or some other variable known at runtime, like their login info.

Comment: If you test the code with the single queries, do they return? I doubt the issue you're encountering has anything to do with the UNION: you could have issue as having more rows than expected (e.g. the phone numbers might appear equal, but they have some spaces/special characters that make them different), but if you have zero rows, it means both the queries are returning zero rows

Answer (score 0):

If you want distinct rows that are in *both* sets, then you want something like `intersect` not `union`.  For instance:

```
SELECT DriverPhone
FROM Transactions
WHERE EstablishmentCode = @ec 
INTERSECT
SELECT PhoneNumber 
FROM Connection
WHERE EstablishmentCode = @ec AND Dispatcher = @disp;
```

You can read about `INTERSECT` in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx).

If your database doesn't support `intersect`, then just use conditional logic:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DriverPhone
FROM Transactions
WHERE EstablishmentCode = @ec AND
      DriverPhone IN (SELECT c.PhoneNumber 
                      FROM Connection c
                      WHERE c.EstablishmentCode = @ec AND c.Dispatcher = @disp
                     );
```

Note:  This uses `SELECT DISTINCT` in case `Transactions` has duplicate records for a given `DriverPhone`.  The use of `UNION` in the question suggests that you want to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

getDrivers.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ec", "ec");

"ec" was supposed to refer to a string variable val set earlier, so it shouldn't have had quotes.